# Removing @ from the link using javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I a have a string in the following format, here i want to remove the @ from the link,
It should remove the @ only from the link, if it's outside the the link then i should not remove.Is there any way in javascript to achive this?

Note:There will be multiple anchor tags in the string.

Is it possible to do with php?

```
var string="Test <a href='/group/profile/1'>@Test User</a>";
```

The output should be

```
Test <a href='/group/profile/1'>Test User</a>
```

Comment: Do you have there <a> tags in your HTML markup?

Comment: in my HTML it displays as @Test User which is hyperlinked

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.replace('src','target')`, to accomplish your task

```
var string = "Test <a href='/group/profile/1'>@Test User</a>";
string = string.replace('@','');
console.log(string); //Test <a href='/group/profile/1'>Test User</a>
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2wtrK/)

Or you can do,

```
var string = "Test <a href='/group/profile/1'>@Test User</a>";
string = string.split('@').join('');
console.log(string); //Test <a href='/group/profile/1'>Test User</a>
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2wtrK/1/)

Comment: This will also remove `@` if the string is `Test @ <a href=...` which according to the OP shouldn't happen

Comment: @asprin yeah, replace will replace the first instance, but OP's case is does not seem so.. That's why i answered this way..

Comment: This is removing if there is any @ outside the link

Comment: i need to remove the @ only if it is inside the anchor tag

Comment: Also there will be multiple anchor tags in the string

Answer (score 0):

@rajaprabhu-aravindasamy nailed it. Use the `str.replace` function.

```
console.log("Test <a href='/group/profile/1'>@Test User</a>".replace('@',''));
```

Comment: And how is this any different from Rajaprabhu's answer? Why post the same thing again?

Comment: Lol I answered before he edited it to print to the console. Bad timing?

Comment: Not referring to the `console.log()` part, but the method used (`replace()`) which is the same

Answer (score 0):

First get the text value of anchor tag as below :

```
var linkText = $('a').text();
```

it will return you only the link value
then replace it as you want to  just like that :

```
var newText = linkText.replace('@','');
```

now put that text into anchor tag text again as follows:

```
$('a').text(newText);
```

Might be this will help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tZUD9/)

Check this snippet,

```
$('a').text(function(){
    return $(this).text().replace('@','')
});
```

Use **[`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** jQuery method.

Comment: here my link is in a string, i need to loop through the links in the string and need to replace the @